# Is there a way to disable the Google Chrome power saving mode with code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

By default, Google Chrome activates the power saving mode on my new MacBook. I was working with Matter.js, and now the frame rate looks very bad. I know that I just can disable it, but maybe other users would see it with a very bad frame rate. Is there a way to tell Google Chrome `Hey Google, please use full power for this website`? Or is there a way to check if its enabled, and then adjust the frame rate with the code?

Comment: the API to detect power saving mode, I think, it is still in development https://github.com/w3c/battery/issues/9#issuecomment-1567356584